# How to merge the different lines of files?

Tags: awk, sort, paste

What is the fastest command line way to merge the different lines of files? For example, I have two files:

a.txt:

```
foo  
bar
foobar
```

b.txt

```
foo
foobar
line
by
bar
```

And I would like to get the following output:

```
foo
bar
foobar
line
by
```

Is there any fast way to merge files like the example above? (The order of the lines isn't important)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `awk seen` if you don't want to sort the file:

```
$ awk '!seen[$0]++' a.txt b.txt
foo  
bar
foobar
line
by
```

Comment: Does it delete the duplicated lines in a single file?

Comment: @KrisztiánBenda, it just print the uniq lines in each file.

Comment: @KrisztiánBenda you can redirect the out to another file, if required.

Comment: Thanks @SivaPrasath for your comment. It seems to me _seen_ is not a valid command in my environment. And `apt-get install seen` does not find it.

Comment: @KrisztiánBenda It's an associative array in `awk`. You may use any array name and `seen` is often used for these kinds of operations. `awk '!p[$0]++'` would work just as well. Note that this solution is appropriate for reasonably large amounts of data, but that memory consumption grows with the number of unique lines in the input.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ sort -u a.txt b.txt
bar
by
foo
foobar
line
```

This would sort the (combined) contents of the two files, removing the duplicate lines.  The downside is that if a line is duplicated in one of the files, this would also be removed.

To write the result to `c.txt`, use

```
sort -u -o c.txt a.txt b.txt
```

or a standard redirection

```
sort -u a.txt b.txt >c.txt
```

Comment: Fastest/shortest is perhaps `sort -u {a,b,-oc}.txt` then ?

Comment: @steve Gah! I would avoid that. That requires a shell that understands brace expansions, and a `sort` implementation that allows for options to come _after_ the operands on the command line.  It's far safer to just be explicit, at least with the command line options and their arguments.  You may use `sort -u -o c.txt [ab].txt` if you want.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your desired output, I presume that you just want both files merged with only unique strings.

In which case, `cat`, `sort` and `uniq` can do this for you:

```
cat a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq > c.txt
```

`cat` opens the contents of both files

`sort` sorts the output alphabetically

`uniq` lists only unique strings

`> c.txt` puts all of the output in a new file `c.txt`

Comment: sort command is more enough to do..

Comment: so I have learned.. that being said the answer is still an alternative, albeit uneccessarily long-winded (relatively anyway) working answer.

Comment: this is also a fast method.